# How do I find the correct url to send curl POST request to?

Tags: http, post, curl, request

I am trying to use curl to send a POST request with json.

I use Live HTTP Headers and get the url to send the request to. However it comes back "request denied. you do not have permission to access this page?"

How do I find the correct url?

from Live Http headers, i can see the json data {"var1":"val1","var2":"val2",...}

so i use the following curl command:

curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -o output.html -L "http://domain.com/theurl" -d '{"var1":"val1","var2":"val2",...}'

Comment: Do you have permissions?

Answer (score 1):

There may be other parts of the request you observed using Live HTTP Headers that allowed your browser to access that URL, such as a cookie value that indicated your session information or user credentials. If Live HTTP Headers has the ability to view those headers and/or cookies, you could grab them and include them in your `curl` request using additional `-H 'Header: value'` arguments.

[HTTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) may also be used, in which case you should pass your username and password to `curl` with `--user name:password`.

Comment: i use -b cookie -c cookie with which i think curl can automatically handle the cookies?

you are saying "request denied" does not mean wrong url?

i also tried -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" but got the same message.

other things include:
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: ....
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip

which i dont think are necessary?

Comment: `-b cookie -c cookie` won't be useful unless you start by specifying a cookie. `-c cookie` just writes the cookies _received_ during the request to the cookie jar file, but if you didn't begin by passing any then it wouldn't know how to authenticate you. (Just to confirm... _is_ this URL authenticated?)

Comment: yes, i have to login the website first. i started with cookies. my code used to work until the site request changed to json (and the url change).

Comment: i think you might be right about the cookies. "Since curl and libcurl are plain HTTP clients without any knowledge of or capability to handle javascript, such cookies will not be detected or used." i checked the javascript and do see functions for cookies.

Comment: i am confused about the cookies. according to curl docs, -c stores the received cookies, -b sends cookies with the request. then it says curl cannot detect javascript cookies. so -b -c only handle non-javascript cookies? "Often, if you want to mimic what a browser does on such web sites, you can record web browser HTTP traffic when using such a site and then repeat the cookie operations using curl or libcurl." i am not sure how to do that..